# storyboard navigation Item link to a uiviewcontroller

Tags: xcode4

I create a split view project, on the iPhone's storyboard, i drag a bar button item to the navigation right and change the style Add, and i drag a view controller to the storyboard, so i use control-drag to build the link, and change the uiviewcontroller's custom class "AddViewController", when i run the project and push the DetailViewController, it is black view.

And i have input the code on the AddViewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"        bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the reason
On the my create  "AddCreateViewController", i should comment the function.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```